# Where and why is the VERBOSE environment variable set to "no" in my Ubuntu installation?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, gcc, makefile, cmake

This is more of a curiosity than anything, but it has stumped me so I decided to share it with the world. On my Ubuntu 12.04 machine, the following environment variable is set (apparently on boot) in my bash shell, and for the life of me I cannot find where this happens:

```
VERBOSE=no
```

I build code with `cmake`, which produces a Makefile that disables compiler jabbering by this bit of cleverness:

```
$(VERBOSE).SILENT
```

To be clear, the `.SILENT` on its own is interpreted as a command by `make`, but if `VERBOSE` is set to anything at all then the command will be unrecognized and `make` will skip over it, resulting in jibber jabber.

This is not a problem on my other machines that run Fedora, so I assume it is specific to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

There is a a file in `/etc/default` - `/etc/default/rcS` - (also in Debian) which sets this variable.

See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man5/rcS.5.html

It controls various bootup things, but perhaps it is inherited into all users environment via /etc/profile or something in your specific case?

[Edit: this is not happening where I just tried it in Xubuntu 13.04 so it may well be something specific to your case]